# PHP SQL Query 2 Tables

Tags: php

I need to query the database with a php query.

I need to get the id that matches $somevalue and the with that ID query table 2 so I can get a field value contained in that row where the id is found.

```
$somevalue = '123';


Select id from table1 where $somevalue = id

...so we have the ID ... now we query table 2

select id, field2 from table2 where id = $id

echo $id;
echo $field2
```

How can I do this in a php query?

Comment: PHP doesn't have queries. SQL does.

Comment: I think, you're looking for [`join`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.0%2Fen%2Fjoin.html&ei=XaY0Uev6CMX2sgae8oHABA&usg=AFQjCNGXZQycUZ9UHnvO4i2-l6UslF5wRA&sig2=2GIxQIwfdDigTjxvYdWilA&bvm=bv.43148975,d.Yms).

Comment: why would you want to fetch "id" from table1, when you are already comparing $somevalue with id

Comment: What do u have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inner join

```
SELECT table2.id table2.field FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id
```

haven't test the code, and i am fairy new to SQL (joins). But you see the patern :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this.

```
 select t2.id, t2.field2 from table2 t2, table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.id = $someValue
```

Full Code is as below

```
$query = sprintf("select t2.id, t2.field2 from table2 t2, table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.id = '%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($somevalue));

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['field2'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax should look like:

```
Select id from table1 where id = $somevalue
```

But why you want the same id, with which you are searching? You could directly do this:

```
select id, field2 from table2 where id = $somevalue
```

Looks like complete mess :(

Anyway, you can [Check This link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) on how to execute queries in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 as t1 Left JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t1.id = ".$somevalue.""
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using a `JOIN`, here is an example using the the code from the question

```
SELECT t2.field2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
   ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id = $someValue
```

What doesn't look right here is joining the tables on their `Id` columns. This is typically the primary key and unlikely to be used in both sides of a join.

A join is made from one table to another to reconstruct the data model. To make this a little more concrete I will change `table1` to `People` and `table2` to `Addresses`. The following query gets the `StreetName` for a particular person via the `People` table. In this case the `People` table has a column `AddressId` which holds the `Id` for this person in the Addresses table

```
SELECT a.StreetName
FROM People p
JOIN Addresses a
   ON p.AddressId = a.id
WHERE t1.id = $someValue
```

You can then apply whatever mechanism PHP offers to run the query